# Avoid custom itemize labels dislocating to the left

Tags: itemize, enumitem, alignment

If in LaTeX I have an itemize environment and I type something like this:

```
\begin{itemize*}
  \item[long item]              text text text text text text text 
  \item[item]                   text
  \item[very very long item]    text text text text text 
\end{itemize*}
```

The outcome looks something like that:

```
    [page border]
           v
           |
        lon|g item text text text ...  
           |  item text text text text ... 
   very lon|g item text text .... 
           |
           |
```

How can I avoid this behavior (going over the page border), so that instead it looks something like this:

```
           |long item      text text text ...  
           |item           text text text text ... 
           |very long item text text ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to adjust your `align`ment, margins and `widest` component:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item[long item]
    text text text text text text text 
  \item[item]
    text
  \item[very very long item]
    text text text text text 
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[align=left, widest={very very long item},leftmargin=*]
  \item[long item]
    text text text text text text text 
  \item[item]
    text
  \item[very very long item]
    text text text text text 
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, if you're not concerned about breaking the list around the page boundary, you can set it inside a table (`tabular`).

Comment: Is there no better way then manually typing the widest item? I mean tabular for example also finds out which is the widest itself, without a manual tag.

Comment: @Hebol: You could specify a width of `labelwidth`, or measure it and use that as the width. Finally, it would probably be possible to define your own environment that processes all `\item[*]` items within that list, extracting the widest element, and using that as the measure for `widest`. For a small number of lists or short lists themselves it shouldn't be a problem, right? Do you have many of these lists?